# Не запускается эмулятор Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

В консоли выводит:
/Volumes/GEEKART/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_22
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554

Виртуальный девайс загружается, и зависает на "starting app". И дальше жди хоть час, хоть два...

Comment: можете попробовать не стандартный эмулятор, а, например, genymotion

Comment: а genymotion есть в бесплатном варианте? Я вижу только платный

Comment: есть конечно! Как только вы зарегистрируетесь, у вас появится новый пункт меню - `Download`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд лучше использовать [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) и работает быстрее и глюков меньше.

Comment: А где его бесплатно взять?

Comment: Он есть в бесплатном варианте. Вот [тут](http://pr0andr0id.blogspot.ru/2015/01/jdk-eclipse-adt-windows-81-x64.html) в самом конце статьи все рассказано.

Comment: Смотрите пункт 10 в статье. Хотя статья старая но актуальная до сих пор. Чтобы скачать бесплатную версию надо зарегистрироваться на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Genimotions, он гораздо быстрее и удобнее. 
Можно скачать [тут.](https://www.genymotion.com)